# How to calculate rows count for every date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
id | reg_date
 1 | 01-02-2019
 2 | 01-02-2019
 3 | 01-02-2019
 4 | 02-02-2019
 5 | 02-02-2019
 6 | 03-02-2019
```

I need to calculate rows count for every date (new users in my case):

```
count | reg_date
    3 | 01-02-2019
    5 | 02-02-2019
    6 | 03-02-2019
```

My query is:

```
SELECT @cnt:=@cnt+count AS count, reg_date
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, reg_date
      FROM users, (select @cnt:=0) x
     group by reg_date
  ) x
 order by reg_date
```

But how to calculate rows count from some date? For the last day\week, for example.

```
count | reg_date
    6 | 03-02-2019
```

Thank you!:)

Comment: Where does time1 come from?

Comment: What is the data type for column `reg_date` in database table `users` ?

Comment: There's no time1 here. Step 1. Store dates using a date data type. Step 2. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: sorry, time1 it is - reg_date

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in getting total users count **upto** a particular date, you don't really need to use Session variables. Instead, you can simply do `COUNT(*)` aggregation with `WHERE` clause filtering the result-set upto the specific date.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM users 
WHERE reg_date <= '2019-02-03'   -- Your input date here
```

Also, note that MySQL date format is **YYYY-mm-dd**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL 8, you can use the `row_number()` window function to calculate the counts:

```
SELECT max(rn) AS count, reg_date
FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY reg_date) AS rn
           , reg_date
      FROM users) AS x
GROUP BY reg_date
ORDER BY reg_date;
```

```
count       reg_date  
----------  ----------
3           2019-01-02
5           2019-02-02
6           2019-03-02
```

[db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8636e443082ee784f8f7c889471464b5)